# How to remove special characters from a XML

Tags: c#, xml, special-characters

I have an xml file. I want to remove all of the special characters in it using C#.

The special characters include:

1. `+`
2. `-`
3. `/`
4. `_`

etc.

Comment: Do you literally want to remove them all including `<` and `>`?  It won't be an XML file anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : Load Xml file to string

```
public string ReadFileToString(string filePath)
{
 StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
 string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
 streamReader.Close();
 return text;
}
```

Setp 2: Remove all the occurance of special char by using the function

```
public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
{
    //change regular expression as per your need
    return Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```

Setp 3 : Save file

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
 doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
 doc.Save("data.xml");
```

Comment: Why are you loading the file into an XML document in step 1? Why not just load it as normal text and save all that overhead? In fact, why treat the document as XML at all?

Comment: @Jordan - I am just providing the Algorithm than there are no of way to do the one things..............Step 2 is the heart of the my algo...step1 and step 3 is just to support it

Comment: I suppose my point is that your answer promotes a non-performant practice by unnecessarily instantiating a relatively processor- and memory-intensive class. Twice. Why not edit to do it in a performant way so that future viewers of your answer don't pick up a bad habit?

Comment: Very nice. I still have a gripe that you are loading it into an XML doc in step 3 but I suppose there could be legitimate reason for that.