# Remove special characters from inner text xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I have xml of this type

```
<STUDENT_NAME>
    <STUDENT_NAME_QUALIFIERS>
        <DATE_RANGE DateFrom='2001-01-01' DateThru='2015-06-22' />
    </STUDENT_NAME_QUALIFIERS>
    <STUDENT_NAME_SEARCH_PARAMETERS>
        <NameFirst>GANGA>TOM</NameFirst>
        <NameLast>RAJEEV & SUMAN</NameLast>
    </STUDENT_NAME_SEARCH_PARAMETERS>
</STUDENT_NAME>
```

want to remove the special characters from the inner text. How to do this ?

Comment: The sample does not show valid XML... Do you actually have just text that pretends to be XML but is not? Also consider clarifying how *special* are characters you want to eliminate.

Comment: I just posted part of xml, want to remove "<,>,&,%,",' all these special char

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591940/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-a-xml

Comment: This is *not XML*. Generally HTML parser is more forgiving (as HTML in a wild is pretty much never valid HTML), so you can try use HtmlAgilityPack to parse your text and hope you can rebuild XML out of it...

Comment: @DavidTansey - no, this is not duplicate as this question is "how to convert text into structured document (like XML)" and not "how to remove some characters from valid XML". It is different common question on SO, but I can't find duplicate easily.

Comment: How about assigning it to a string and replacing < > & % " '